Keyboard remapping not possible for four keys
I've just bought an Asus notebook with a keyboard that does not suit me: three keys are useless and I would like to remap them but I'm not sure that's possible.
This notebook came with Windows11 Professional installed, I replaced it with Debian12. This problem is the same as the one described here
On the right-hand side of the keyboard, the first four keys above the numeric keypad are, from left to right: Calculator (launches calculator), CE (= Clear Entry), -/+ (Change Sign) and On/Off.
The problem is that  F9 and + / - keys have the exact same function and also CE and Del key act the exact same: their keycodes and scancodes are identical.
Why, even after I removed Windows11, are these keys still linked? I looked in the Bios but I couldn't find anything about the keyboard. Is there a physical link inside the keyboard between these keys? Is it possible to remove this link?

You might be able to remap them forcibly with xbindkeys and xdotool.  But that's an awful odd one.

Likely, those keys cannot easily be remapped. Those keys are controlled by the physical key board wiring, by the internal keyboard decoder, and by BIOS (F-key behavior). Use an external keyboard, or return the PC, if it does not please you.

In fact, in the Bios, there was indeed something about the behavior of the Fn key, but I had no idea that this could have anything to do with a problem concerning four other different keys. As I'm getting used to this mapping, I'll leave this problem aside. At least I know a little more about its origin; that's a step forward.Thanks for your answers
